# Converting USDZ to OBJ/GLB/GLTF in C

Tags: c, 3d, usdz

I'm working on a project that requires converting USDZ files to more commonly used 3D file formats such as OBJ, GLB, or GLTF. I need to accomplish this task programmatically using C.

Can anyone provide guidance or recommendations on how to approach this task in C? Are there any existing libraries or tools that support USDZ to OBJ/GLB/GLTF conversion in C? Alternatively, if there's a C library for handling USD files, I could attempt to implement the conversion logic myself.

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I've researched various libraries and tools, but most of them seem to support higher-level languages like Python or JavaScript. I'm specifically looking for a solution that can be implemented in C due to project constraints.